# access a module1 DefaultController from module2 DefaultController yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to access a module's model from another module ,

ex:

```
protected/modules/module1/DefaultController
protected/modules/module2/DefaultController
```

i want to access module1 models from module2 ,

i tried

```
Yii::app()->getModule('module1');
$m = new module1;
```

it showing the error

```
include(module1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you did not declare your module in config (main.php):

```
'modules'=>array(
     ...
     'module2'=>array(
         ...
     ),
),
```

Also check whether you have named the class module. It should be `Module1Module`.

And I can see that you do not have a the correct directory structure of the module. Controllers should be in the directory `сontrollers`:

```
/protected/modules/module1
   Module1Module.php
   controllers/
      defaultController.php 
   views/
      index.php
```